# How do I find unique values in a list of javascript objects over multiple keys?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of javascript objects. Here is an example:

```
[{'first': 'Mary', 'last':'Smith', 'task':'managing'},
{'first': 'Mary', 'last':'Smith', 'task':'research'},
{'first': 'Henry', 'last':'Ford', 'task':'assembling'},
{'first':'Henry', 'last':'Winkler', 'task':'acting;}]
```

and I want to find all elements in the array that are distinct in first AND last name. The output I'm looking for is of the form:

```
[{'first': 'Mary', 'last':'Smith'},
 {'first': 'Henry', 'last':'Ford'},
 {'first': 'Henry', 'last':'Winkler'}]
```

How do I do this in javascript?

Comment: Nice problem, have you tried anything so far or have thought any ideas on how to attack it?

Comment: Thanks. After a while of searching around, reading documentation (lodash, underscore, plain JS, etc) to no avail, I tried looping through the initial array, checking to see if objects with the first and last values already exist in the new array, and if not pushing the new elements to the new array, but I'm not sure how to see if an object with multiple keys already exists in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `Map` for this:

```
var m = new Map();
arr.forEach(function(obj){
    var name = obj.first + ' ' + obj.last;
    if(!m.has(name)){
       m.set(name, { first : obj.first, last : obj.last});
    }
});
var uniques = Array.from(m.values());
```

Comment: Clever! I didn't think of turning all the values for the keys of interest into one large string to search over. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good time to roll out the new ES6 set

```
var s = new Set();
arr.forEach(a => s.add({'first':a.first, 'last': a.last}))
var myArr = Array.from(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Minusfour You are just ahead of me. I got same solution.

```
array.forEach( function (arrayItem)
{
   if(hashMap[arrayItem.first + arrayItem.last] == 0){
     hashMap[arrayItem.first + arrayItem.last] = 1;
     finalArray.push(arrayItem);
   }
});
```